# Unable to redirect at other page in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

Unable to redirect at other page in react js.
Using below code :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

 handleClick = () => {
        browserHistory.push('/login');
    };

 setRedirect = () => {
    this.setState({
      redirect: true
    })
  }
```

On render function :

```
<button onClick={this.setRedirect}>Redirect</button>
```

I have searched the following link on stack overflow:

[First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879155/how-to-redirect-to-a-page-in-react-native)

[Second Link](https://hub.packtpub.com/using-react-router-client-side-redirecting/)

[Third Link](https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a)

I have searched on above site but didn't get the perfect solution. Please help me.

Comment: you have to redirect to the `/login` page?

Comment: WHere is ur handleClick called? Is your browserHistory imported? Atleast Share required code for faster & better solution from community

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-the-new-react-router-dom-of-reactjs